# Exception encountered during context initialization. BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, heroku

I'm new at Heroku and I'm trying to deploy an app but I have got an issue I don't know how to fix. I've tried several things (posts from here), changing my pom, my application.properties, my annotations, but nothing works. The app works fine on my local machine (Before it was with MySQL, now it's postgresql).

please help!! What I'm missing?
Thanks in advance

P.S. I've already tried with hibernate & hibernate-entitymanager dependencies and without them.

*application.properties*

```
# Database Config

spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
    username: ${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
    password: ${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

#
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl

#
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

#
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
```

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.userFront</groupId>
    <artifactId>userFront</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>UserFront</name>
    <description>User Frontend for Online Banking Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

*Error log*

```
2018-07-13T16:58:53.793927+00:00 app[web.1]: :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)
2018-07-13T16:58:53.794005+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-13T16:58:54.133032+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:54.112  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.userfront.UserFrontApplication       : Starting UserFrontApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on fdbdd3a1-44b9-418d-abc5-296f6bc31cce with PID 4 (/app/target/userFront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by u43547 in /app)
2018-07-13T16:58:54.133389+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:54.133  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.userfront.UserFrontApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-13T16:58:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-07-13T16:58:54.876309+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:54.875  INFO 4 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6e5e91e4: startup date [Fri Jul 13 16:58:54 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-13T16:58:58.709414+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:58.709  INFO 4 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 40539 (http)
2018-07-13T16:58:58.744327+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:58.743  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2018-07-13T16:58:58.746345+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:58.746  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2018-07-13T16:58:59.118478+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:59.118  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-13T16:58:59.118691+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:59.118  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4252 ms
2018-07-13T16:58:59.801817+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:59.801  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13T16:58:59.802726+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:59.802  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13T16:58:59.802783+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:59.802  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13T16:58:59.802948+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:59.802  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13T16:58:59.803154+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:59.803  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13T16:58:59.805747+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:59.805  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-07-13T16:58:59.805979+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:58:59.805  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.041583+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:59:02.041  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-13T16:59:02.046049+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:59:02.045  WARN 4 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
2018-07-13T16:59:02.065343+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:59:02.063  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2018-07-13T16:59:02.094597+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:59:02.091  WARN 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140043+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 16:59:02.138 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140047+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140068+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140071+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140073+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140075+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140077+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140078+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140080+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140082+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140084+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140086+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140087+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140089+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140091+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140094+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140093+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140096+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140098+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140100+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.userfront.UserFrontApplication.main(UserFrontApplication.java:14) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140102+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140103+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140105+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140107+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140109+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [userFront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140111+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [userFront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140112+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [userFront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140114+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [userFront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140122+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140153+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140380+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140383+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140386+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140388+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140390+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140394+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 24 common frames omitted
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140396+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140398+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140400+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140403+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[userFront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140404+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140406+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 30 common frames omitted
2018-07-13T16:59:02.140408+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-13T16:59:02.266893+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-07-13T16:59:02.251360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Error log without hibernate-entitymanager

```
2018-07-13T18:17:31.247870+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 18:17:31.247  WARN 4 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-07-13T18:17:31.256941+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 18:17:31.256  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2018-07-13T18:17:31.271302+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 18:17:31.271  WARN 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280257+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-07-13 18:17:31.279 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280260+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280268+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280271+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280273+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280274+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280277+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280278+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280280+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280282+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280284+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280286+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280288+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280289+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280291+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280293+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280295+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280297+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280298+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280300+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.userfront.UserFrontApplication.main(UserFrontApplication.java:14) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280302+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280304+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280306+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280308+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280309+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [userFront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280311+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [userFront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280313+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [userFront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280317+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [userFront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280323+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280325+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280327+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280332+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280333+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280335+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280337+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280338+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280340+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280342+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 24 common frames omitted
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280343+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [create table user (user_id int8 not null, email varchar(255) not null, enabled boolean not null, first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), password varchar(255), phone varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary_account_id int8, savings_account_id int8, primary key (user_id))]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280345+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280347+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280349+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:420) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280350+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.createTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280352+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280353+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280355+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280356+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280358+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2018-07-13T18:17:31.280360+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work` seems to be the culprit

Comment: Remove the `hibernate-entitymanager` from your list of dependencies.

Comment: Thx for replies. I've edited my post adding a 2nd log without the hibernate-entitymanager dependency

Comment: "Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [create table user ..." `user` is a reserved keyword. You can't (easily) create a table with that name

Comment: problem solved after renaming the table. Thx a lot